# Do I need to specify NOT NULL on a column that has a CHECK constraint?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
doctorName VARCHAR(50) CHECK(LEN(doctorName ) > 0)
```

Should I specify NOT NULL on the preceding declaration? 
A NULL value will not be permitted, since It will not pass the CHECK constraint... So what is the purpose of specifing NOT NULL under this circumstance ?

Answer (score 4):

You either have to specify `NOT NULL`:

```
doctorName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL CHECK(LEN(doctorName ))
```

Or check in the constraint:

```
doctorName VARCHAR(50) CHECK(LEN(doctorName ) > 0 AND doctorName IS NOT NULL)
```

The first is preferable because `NOT NULL` is built into SQL, so the optimizer can take advantage of it.

Why is this necessary?  If the name is `NULL`, then the comparison returns `NULL`.  `CHECK` constraints work differently from `WHERE` clauses and `CASE` expressions.  A `CHECK` constraint fails only when the expression evaluates to FALSE.  So, both TRUE and `NULL` satisfy the constraint.  On the other hand, `WHERE` clauses and `CASE` expressions treat `NULL` as FALSE, rather than TRUE.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=83ff7c4864ab2a714c2fef7359fe2e4b) is a db<>fiddle example showing that `NULL` values are not caught by a `check` constraint.

Comment: Gordon, can you add any reference to "A CHECK constraint fails only when the expression evaluates to FALSE"?

Comment: You are right. I checked it in Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2, SQL Server, and MariaDB. MySQL does not enforce it since it ignores CHECK constraints anyway. +1

Comment: @TheImpaler . . . I can't actually find the reference in the Microsoft documentation, but that is how check constraints are defined to work.